# How to install libpng correctly?

Tags: c, ubuntu, linker, libpng

I am trying to access png pixel data in my C code on. I found this library [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html). I downloaded latest version from this site, I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I followed the instructions in the INSTALL file. Everything went well. And then I tried to compile with gcc this piece of [code](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html). But I received this:

```
/tmp/ccWa9LDO.o: In function `read_png_file':
test.c:(.text+0x13c): undefined reference to `png_sig_cmp'
test.c:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
test.c:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
test.c:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
test.c:(.text+0x20c): undefined reference to `png_init_io'
test.c:(.text+0x220): undefined reference to `png_set_sig_bytes'
test.c:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `png_read_info'
test.c:(.text+0x252): undefined reference to `png_get_image_width'
test.c:(.text+0x271): undefined reference to `png_get_image_height'
test.c:(.text+0x290): undefined reference to `png_get_color_type'
test.c:(.text+0x2af): undefined reference to `png_get_bit_depth'
test.c:(.text+0x2c4): undefined reference to `png_set_interlace_handling'
test.c:(.text+0x2e3): undefined reference to `png_read_update_info'
test.c:(.text+0x2fc): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
test.c:(.text+0x36f): undefined reference to `png_get_rowbytes'
test.c:(.text+0x3b2): undefined reference to `png_read_image'
/tmp/ccWa9LDO.o: In function `write_png_file':
test.c:(.text+0x430): undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
test.c:(.text+0x461): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
test.c:(.text+0x49c): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
test.c:(.text+0x4cd): undefined reference to `png_init_io'
test.c:(.text+0x4e6): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
test.c:(.text+0x559): undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
test.c:(.text+0x572): undefined reference to `png_write_info'
test.c:(.text+0x58b): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
test.c:(.text+0x5bf): undefined reference to `png_write_image'
test.c:(.text+0x5d8): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
test.c:(.text+0x607): undefined reference to `png_write_end'
/tmp/ccWa9LDO.o: In function `process_file':
test.c:(.text+0x692): undefined reference to `png_get_color_type'
test.c:(.text+0x6be): undefined reference to `png_get_color_type'
test.c:(.text+0x6db): undefined reference to `png_get_color_type'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand it because I would expect that if there is problem with installation I would get errors just for including `png.h`.

Comment: Do you have libpng12-dev installed? sudo apt-get install libpng12-dev the files required for using it in development is generally in a -dev package on Debian and derivates.

Comment: It seems that you are not linking against the libpng library.

Comment: @deepy those are generally the header files. OP has a *linker error,* though, and not a compiler error.

Comment: Show exactly your compilation command. Order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot!

Comment: Sorry I am just starting writing under linux, I just used gcc my_code.c. @TheParamagneticCroissant what do you mean by linking against the libpng library ?

Comment: @MichalKrakovsky Just google it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You said in the comments that you use `gcc my_code.c`, try

```
gcc my_code.c -lpng
```

The `-l` flag links a library, in this case `libpng12-dev`.

Linking means that your compiler adds the code from all the object files to create a single executable file. The object files are the separate compiled source code files (the `.o` files).

Comment: thanks, this helped with the compilation. Now I have problem running the program. I get this error message:  `./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I think that numbers there represents only version of that library. When I try `gcc my_code.c -lpng12` I get few lines of these: `test.c:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to \`png_set_longjmp_fn'`. I tried `gcc my_code.c -lpng16` as well and the error from comnent above still persists.

Comment: Yes it does indeed only solve the version issue, what if you compile libpng 1.6 from source and try it with the command I said in my answer?

Comment: I compiled it from source I guess, I did it trough make install, not apt-get install.

Comment: You can use `find /usr/lib -name *png*` to find the location and then use `gcc my_code.c -L<location> -lpng16`.

Comment: But I have no longer problem with compilation but with running the compiled program. I tried now compiling like this: `gcc test.c -L/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/ -lpng16`, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I wouldn't know the solution to this problem, I think you should open a new thread for it.

Comment: It may help to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH so it points to the directory that contains libpng16.so.16, before running your program.

Comment: -L/usr/local/lib -lpng on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I don't know english very well, but I will try to help you.
I was getting this issues about 2 days, the solution is so simple, let's see.

try to do this: `gcc my_code.c -lpng`
afterwards you will get some file like `a.out`, then you need to have some picture `png` in same directory.

after, type this: `./a.out png_file.png res.png`

The output file will be called `res.png`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you installed only the PNG processing library. You will have to install the header files that can reference the library installed. So Install 'dev' package also like this

```
 sudo apt-get install libpng12-dev
```

Comment: He obviously does have the header files, since he got through compilation. It's the linkage that is failing.